# rails: configuring CSP for segment analytics js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy

I'm trying to import segment analytics js into my rails 6 project, and struggling with the Content security policy.

I'm not sure how I should set it up.

[Analytics gives me](https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/website/javascript/upgrade-to-ajs2/) an inline script that load the library, and their docs say I should allow also a bunch of other addresses, like:

```
https://cdn.segment.com/v1/projects/<WRITE_KEY>/settings
https://cdn.segment.com/analytics-next/bundles/*
https://cdn.segment.com/next-integrations/integrations/*
```

just including their inline script I'm getting:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: 'nonce-xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx=='". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message: Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

You will need to stick with either the nonce/hash or 'unsafe-inline'. It is better if you can do without 'unsafe-inline', but it is sometimes hard to get nonces or hashes right for all inline scripts. In addition event attributes can't be hashed or nonced so if you have any you'll need to rewrite them with event handlers.